# Can I use management azure api for Azure APIM analytics

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management, apim

I want to use the below API to compute Azure APIM analytics and customize the output of it.

But Microsoft document does not cover the API. Can I use this API or I am missing something.

My concerns is how do I know if Microsoft internally change their API or stop supporting them.
(This API gives me the expected result in Postman with valid authorization)
API post -

```
https://management.azure.com/batch?api-version=2015-11-01
```

Request Body -

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "url": "/subscriptions{subscription_Name}resourceGroups/{resource_group_name}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{APIM_name}/reports/bytime?api-version=2019-01-01&$filter=timestamp ge 2019-03-25T09:41:34.144Z and  timestamp le 2019-04-25T10:41:34.144Z&interval=PT24H",
            "httpMethod": "GET",
            "name": "resource_Guid",
            "requestHeaderDetails": {
                "commandName": "Microsoft_Azure_ApiManagement."
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know about this. I found a similar discussion here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/9271.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if /batch API is documented, even though Azure portal does use it a lot I wouldn't recommend using it unless you find public docs. Azure APIM reports API is documented and supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/reports

Comment: Above link no longer valid, moved to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/api-management-rest